# How to debug syntax error in update statement?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
        Dim uname As String
        uname = Accounts.value
        Dim comStr As String = "UPDATE tbl_User SET UserName=@username1, [Password]=@password1, " &
                                "[Type]=@type1, Fname=@fname1, Mname=@mname1, Lname=@lname1, " &
                                "Address=@address1, City=@city1, State/Province=@State/Province1, " &
                                "Country=@country1, Phone=@phone1, Email=@email1 WHERE UserName=@value1"
        Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(comStr, con)


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username1", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password1", TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type1", ComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname1", TextBox3.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mname1", TextBox4.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname1", TextBox5.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address1", TextBox6.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city1", TextBox7.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State/Province1", TextBox8.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country1", TextBox9.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone1", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox10.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email1", TextBox11.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", TextBox1.Text)


        'Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        'Finally
        con.Close()
        'End Try
```

Comment: `State/Province` is a bad name for a column, escape it like you did Password (or change it).  Also Passwords should never be saved as plain text - hash them...and `ComboBox1.SelectedText` may not do what you think it does.

Comment: ...and phone numbers are not really numbers.  You cant add or subtract  them so they arent numbers.

Comment: Can you post your error message? I expect you might need to enclose your column names with a backtick(`) or single quote(').

Comment: okay. thank you for your replies. :) ill gonna try your suggestions for now.

Comment: error says " Syntax error in UPDATE statement" :)

Comment: thanks for responding. :) i've found a solution. :D

Comment: but the [ ] helped me with the state/province. :)

Answer (score 1):

As per a note in the comments, `State/Province` is not a good name for a column. The parser of most database systems will reject the `/` slash unless the name is delimited.

It sounds that you have found that using square bracket delimiters `[State/Province]` will resolve the problem, but unless you have a large system, it is better to rename the field so that you do not have to keep doing this. Use an underscore instead.